# MongoDB - Get SUM of values INSIDE of the array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have JSON document recorded to MongoDB with structure like so:

```
[{ "SessionKey": "172e3b6b-509e-4ef3-950c-0c1dc5c83bab",
   "Query": {"Date": "2020-03-04"},
   "Flights": [
           {"LegId":"13235",
            "PricingOptions": [
                    {"Agents": [1963108],
                     "Price": 61763.64 },
                    {"Agents": [4035868],
                     "Price": 62395.83 }]},
            {"LegId": "13236",
             "PricingOptions": [{
                        "Agents": [2915951],
                        "Price": 37188.0}]}
                         ...
```

The result I'm trying to get is **"LegId":"sum_per_flight"**, in this case -> {'13235': (61763.64+62395.83), '13236': 37188.0} **and then get flights with price < N**

I've tried to run this pipeline for aggregation step (but it returns list of ALL prices - I don't know how to sum them up properly):

```
result = collection.aggregate([
    {'$match': {'Query.Date': '2020-03-01'}},
    {'$group': {'_id': {'Flight':'$Flights.LegId', 'Price':'$Flights.PricingOptions.Price'}}} ])
```

Also I've tried this pipeline, but it returns 0 for 'total_price_per_flight':

```
result = collection.aggregate({'$project': {
        'Flights.LegId':1,
        'total_price_per_flight': {'$sum': '$Flights.PricingOptions.Price'}
    }})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$unwind` to flatten `Flights` array to able iterate individually.

With `$reduce` operator, we iterate `PricingOptions` array and sum `Price` fields (accumulate prices).

The last step we return your documents into original structure. Before that, you may apply **"get flights with price < N"**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "Query.Date": "2020-03-04"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Flights"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "Flights.LegId": {
        $arrayToObject: [
          [
            {
              k: "$Flights.LegId",
              v: {
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$Flights.PricingOptions",
                  initialValue: 0,
                  in: {
                    $add: [
                      "$$value",
                      "$$this.Price"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      SessionKey: {
        $first: "$SessionKey"
      },
      Query: {
        $first: "$Query"
      },
      Flights: {
        $push: "$Flights"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FUXcQRhvcOs)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I'm new to this, so please help me understand - when I run the solution for my small JSON snippet it doesn't return price sum for each individual LegId [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xz_JGjRBunM). Also, looks like pipeline modifies LegId and Agents values.

Comment: @VenusV can you post please expected result?

Comment: Yes, sure - I'd like to get SUM of all 'Price' fields for each 'LegId' (no matter of 'Agent' field), in case of my JSON snippet I'd like to get result like so -> "13235": 124159.47, "13236": 37188.0, where 124159.47=61763.64+62395.83.

Comment: @VenusV check agian please

Comment: Thank you - now it works perfectly! P.S. I ended up using cropped version (w/o group and replaced $addFields with $project to get only LegId and sum).